# ValueError in matrix multiplication

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication

This is really basic but I am facing some issues with matrix multiplication in my code.

As per np.matmul(x1,x2) documentation --> if x1 and x2 have a shape (n,k) and (k,m) then the output is of the signature (n,k),(k,m)->(n,m).
I have 2 arrays of similar signature mentioned above but when I use np.matmul,  I get a valueError that "Shape of passed values is (1004, 20), indices imply (1004, 1)"

```py
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(1004,1)))
test2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([1,20]))

np.matmul(test1,test2)
```

I expect to see an output array of size (1004,20). Is there any issue here? 
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get the code to work if you do not call pandas:

```
import numpy as np

test1 = np.random.randint(0,10, size=(1004,1)) 
test2 = np.ones([1,20]) 

output = np.matmul(test1,test2)        
print(output.shape) 

>>> (1004, 20)
```

Similarly, the builtin [pandas multiplication](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html#pandas.DataFrame.mul) gives you the right shape, (but lots of `NaNs`):

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(1004,1))) 
test2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([1,20])) 

output = test1 * test2 

print(test1.shape) 
print(test2.shape) 
print(output.shape)

>>> (1004, 1)
>>> (1, 20)
>>> (1004, 20)
```

Seems that your problem comes from calling the numpy function over the dataframes.  The error seems to come from inside the `ndarray` constructor.  This means `numpy` fails to build the `ndarray` returned in [np.matmul](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), perhaps because it was expecting input arrays.  If you really want to mix the libraries like this, you can always grab the underlying `ndarray` that pandas uses, the [DataFrame.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values):

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10, size=(1004,1))) 
test2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones([1,20])) 

output_ndarray = np.matmul(test1.values, test2.values) 
print(output_ndarray.shape)(1004, 20)
>>> (1004, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response, make much sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `np.matmul(test1.values, test2.values)` which removes the index information from the dataframes and gives you a numpy array of the actual values.